# how to use glCopyImage2D

Tags: opengl, textures

I'm trying something like

```
glEnable(texture_2d)
glBindTexture
glCopyTexImage2D
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

I think glCopyTexImage2D won't work with a non-power of two image, so that's one problem; I've also tried glReadPixels, but it's too slow for my purposes.

Comment: Do you know if the problem is in creating the texture or later rendering it?  Does `glCopyTexImage2D` followed by `glGetTexImage` yield the same result as `glReadPixels`? (not recommended as a long-term solution for performance reasons, but as a troubleshoot step to see what's going on with the texture)

Comment: For the power-of-2 restriction, you can use `glTexImage2D` to allocate the texture with a power-of-2 size and passing `NULL` for the data, then `glCopyTexSubImage2D` which allows non power-of-2 dimensions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `glReadPixels` is too slow for you, then `glCopyTexImage2D` and `glCopyTexSubImage2D` aren’t going to be a whole lot faster. On platforms with support for framebuffer objects, like iOS, the recommended (i.e. faster) way to get GPU-rendered image data into a texture is to use that texture as the color attachment for a framebuffer object and render directly into it. That said, if you still want to pursue this method, here’s what you need to do to fix it:

First, you’re passing bad arguments to `glCopyTexImage2D`. The third argument, `internalformat`, should probably be `GL_RGBA` instead of `0`. If you had called `glGetError` after calling `glCopyTexImage2D`, you would probably have gotten `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. See the OpenGL ES 1.1 man pages for [glCopyTexImage2D](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glCopyTexImage2D.xml) and [glCopyTexSubImage2D](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glCopyTexSubImage2D.xml).

Second, as you’ve already observed, `glCopyTexImage2D` requires its width and height arguments to be power-of-two as well. The correct way to deal with this is to allocate a texture image using `glTexImage2D` (you can pass `NULL` for `pixels` here), then use `glCopyTexSubImage2D` to copy your framebuffer contents into a rectangle. Note that `glCopyTexSubImage2D` doesn’t take an `internalformat` argument—because it’s updating a subrectangle of a texture, it uses the texture’s existing format.

For the record, glGetTexImage doesn’t exist in OpenGL ES 1.1 or 2.0, which is why you’re getting an implicit declaration.

Comment: Sounds like I should look into framebuffer objects... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the video card supports non-power of 2 textures if it supports the ARB_texture_non_power_of_two extension.  [See here for info.](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_non_power_of_two.txt)

Answer (score 2):

`glCopyTexImage2D` does work with NPOT image.

NPT image (non-power of two) is limited supported by OpenGLES 2/OpenGL 1 or WebGL, In OpenGLES 3/OpenGL 2 or later it is fully supported.

If you want to copy color attachment of `fbo` to `newTexture`.

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, newTexture);
glTexImage2D(bindTarget, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

glCopyTexSubImage2D(target, level, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height);
```

NPT image will output black color in fragment shader sampling if texture mipmap, magnification filter and repeat mode setting is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To help figure out if the "non-power of two" thing is a problem, use glGetError() like this:

```
printf("error: %#06x\n", glGetError());
```

Put that in different places in your code to make sure what line is causing the problem, then check the error code here: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Error

To copy a texture I did:

```
glCopyTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 0, 0, TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT, 0);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

after binding the texture. Check the docs on those two functions for more info.